# ARIMA modelling in R: Help please

Tags: r, arima

I'm in need of some help in using R (bit of a newbie).
If I use the following code in R

```
arima(adj.close,order=c(2,2,3))
```

it will fit an ARIMA(2,2,3) model to `adj.close`.

My **question** is, do I difference the data before fitting the model or after?

I used function `ndiffs` to get the number of first differences I should take, and the return was `2`.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This question seems better suited to R-help - or simply try out different commands after reading the manual (`?arima`). Read Shumway & Stoffer's ["Some R Time Series Issues"](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/Rissues.htm) for discussion of some quirks of `arima`; note in particular the defaults for `include.mean`. (See also ["an R time series quick fix"](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa3/R_toot.htm) at the web page for *Time series analysis and its applications: with R examples*.)

Comment: I see there is a vote to close the question for it being off topic. You might want to rephrase it so as to put more weight on conceptual understanding and less weight on programming. But maybe there already exists a conceptual question that is the same as yours? You could try searching the site for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You difference the data *before* fitting an ARMA model.

Equivalently, you do not *explicitly* difference the data at all if you are fitting an ARIMA model with integration order `I` equal to the integration order of the series (in your case, order `I=2`); the model has the differencing as an *implicit* first step.

When you write `order=c(2,2,3)` as the argument in the function `arima`, you ask the function to difference the data twice *before* estimating an ARMA(2,3) model.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, if, say,    adj.close     is my raw undifferenced data, should I use    arima(adj.close, order=c(2,2,3))    or should I first do something like    diff.adjclose<-diff(diff(adj.close))    and then arima(diff.adjclose, order=c(2,2,3))    ? (Also, I dont know how to make the r code look "rcode-y" sorry)

Comment: If your raw undifferenced data is integrated of order 2 (as suggested by the output of function `ndiffs`), then your indeed write `arima(adj.close, order=c(2,2,3))`.

Comment: @James: There's a question mark at the top right of the box that appears when you ask a question. Click on that & it explains markdown. Use backticks: \`bit of code` to get `bit of code`.